# How to get single digit after fraction in float value in obj c?

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, nsstring

How to get a single-digit after fraction in a float value? find below what i have tried.

```
NSString *tempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.01f", [[dict objectForKey:@"stringvalue5"] floatValue]]; //"18.15"
DebugLog(@"Str is: %@", tempStr);//18.1
float percentageValue = [tempStr floatValue];//18.1000004
float testFloat = round(percentageValue*10)/10;//18.1000004
```

But i need to get only one digit from stringValue5 how can i?

Comment: It impossible to set `float` to exactly the value 18.1 because 18.1 is not representable in the `float` type. The closest representable value is 18.1000003814697265625. All `float` values are integer multiples of various powers of two. For numbers around 18.1, they are multiples of 2^−19, which is 0.0000019073486328125. You can request one decimal digit when formatting the number into a string. If you want to calculate with single decimal digits after the decimal point, you need to understanding floating-point arithmetic and design calculations for this. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: If you need precise *decimal* floating-point numbers look at `NSDecimal`. HTH

Comment: @EricPostpischil I need tempStr as float value into percentageValue how can i do that?